# Angular - Map/Catch returning same value but receiving error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Basically, I have this following code:

```
let currentTime:number = (new Date()).getTime();
return this.authenticationService.login(credential).map(data => {
  const token = data.token;
  const id = data.id;
  sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify({currentTime, token, id}));
  return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userData'));
}).catch(error => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify({currentTime, error}));
  return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userData'));
});
```

As you can see, either the `map` or the `catch` methods, are returning the same code. When I reach the the `return` statement using the `map` method,  everything runs as expected. But when I reach the `return` at the `catch` section Angular says: `core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per error message suggests, you should return a promise, or an observable,...

```
}).catch(error => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify({currentTime, error}));
  return Observable.of(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userData')));
});
```